# My app will only output "false", not the code I want

Tags: java, android, textview, output

1. I used samples from similar code to make this, unfortunately I'm not to sure what I did wrong.
2. The purpose of this app is to output text entered in a field to a TextView, where I changed the color, when a button is pressed.

---

```
package edu.wmich.project3

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity {

    String txtResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button text =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor0);
        final TextView result = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
        text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {                       
                txtResult= getText(R.id.txtField0).toString();
                result.setText(txtResult);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, the package and imports got into the description.

Comment: What behavior are you currently seeing?

Comment: You fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
txtResult = (findViewById(R.id.txtField0)).toString();
```

will solve...

the problem is that you're using the method **[getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getText%28int%29)** from the Activity which has nothing to do with the TextField you're dealing with.

...what is the type of view of R.id.txtField0? I guess with this you can take it from here.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks! Although now it outputs "android.widget.EditText@4121a7c0"?

Comment: Also R.id.txtField0 is a person name text field widget. Should I use just a plain text field?

Comment: then you have to cast to EditText and get the text from it..like ((EditText)findViewById(...)).getText()